# Usage of tenses

Tags: tenses

Can the simple present sentence 'I read nearly every day' also be a simple past, because the past tense is also 'read'?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Without any context, it is impossible to say which one it is **in written English**. However, with context, or when spoken, you will know immediately.

Context is vitally important in English.

A: "I am (present) sorry to hear you are (present) ill. What do (present) you do all day?"
B: "I read (present) nearly every day." (present = /ri:d/)

A: "I was (past) sorry to hear you were  (past) ill. What did  (past) you do all day?"
B: "I read  (past) nearly every day." (past = /rɛd/

Comment: That answers my question. Thank you.